# How to use colleagues systems as servers to run Storm

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, router, lan

At times when connectivity to the internet is not very good or unavailable, my colleagues and I are considering using each other's laptops as servers (Storm supervisor nodes), to run our Apache Storm prototype applications.

As of now, we aren't able to ping each other's IP's and I couldn't find a way to make my Mac OS firewall to allow specific IP's. Our IP's begin with 192.168.x.x. The WiFi router's IP is also shown to be 192.168.x.x.

We are a startup, and there's no separate IT team.

Questions:
1. Is this a worthwhile, sensible idea?
2. How do we configure our systems to be able to communicate with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the same class of addresses (192.168.x.x.) given by the same router, the systems should be able to correctly communicate.

First make sure the router itself is not blocking ICMP or other protocols between stations (if you have access to it).

Then, what you have to do is allow the ports used by the Apache Storm and the applications designed in it through the MAC's firewalls.

To allow a specific app to receive incoming connections, add it using Firewall Options:

- Open System Preferences.
- Click the Security or Security & Privacy icon.
- Select the Firewall tab.
- Click the lock icon in the preference pane, then enter the admin/password.
- Click the Firewall Options button
- Click the Add Application (+) button.
- Select the app you want to allow incoming connection privileges for.
- Click Add, OK.

It also is possible to open a specific port, although you'll need to use Terminal. In OS X 10.10 you use the pfctl command (use man  for instructions). In earlier versions of OS X you can use ipfw (which is now depreciated). Follow these general steps to open a specific port in OS X(lets say we want to open 8080 for example):

- Open Terminal (Go --> Utilites).
- Edit `/etc/pf.conf`

  pass in proto tcp from any to any port 8080

Save the changes.

To apply the changes:

```
sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.conf
```

Turn of and back on the firewall so that the rules apply.

Now port 8080 will be open to connections. You can do this for any port of the storm prototype apps you need.